# How to merge two background sprites in Unity so that there won't be a line between the merging sides?

Tags: merge, background, sprite, unity-game-engine

> Hello guys, I am making a 2D platformer game in which I will be adding background sprites. And while doing so, I will be joining many(let's say two) sprites to make it look like one long background. However, when I join two background sprites, a line is visible at the joining point, making it evident that I merged two sprites there. How do I make it look like it is a single image? How do I remove the line between them? Please help me fix this. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this problem too, i solved it indirectly by creating a third joiner sprite that is a child of the first sprite and placed at its end (covering the line). As the backgrounds move the third sprite always covers the joining line. The joining sprite can be a a drawing of anything eg clouds, wall, etc